# PHP get the IMG Tag of upper level A Tag href link?

Tags: php

How to get a img of uppper leve a tag href?

I need to change my content img src.

So, I want to get the uppper leve a tag href first.

In my limited experience with that

Now Code

```
<a href="data/abc.png"><img src="test.png"></a>
```

I want change to

```
<a href="data/abc.png"><img src="data/abc.png"></a>
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

any suggest?  should me neef to use preg_replace?

Comment: Change how? Dynamically when something happens on the page? Can you please give us more details?

Comment: I using php to change database content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Using jQuery*** you can do like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').attr('src', $('img').parent('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').attr('src', $('img').parent('a').attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="data/abc.png">
  <img src="test.png">
</a>
```

Note:- if your document have multiple `<a>` with `<img>` in it, above code will change `src` of all.So be careful.

***In PHP*** (update your code like below):

```
<a href="<?php php code to get href value ?>">
  <img src="<? write the same php code to get href value ?>">
</a>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks , I try ues jQuery to process it. Thanks a lot